# Spring : Do I require to define separate TransactionManager for 2 data sources?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, migration

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I have 2 data-sources defined for different types of tasks. Currently, during migration from XML to Java, I stumbled upon a requirement to add a new `HibernateTransactionManager` object for `@Transactional` to work. For the 2 different data-sources, I have 2 separate `SessionFactory` instances. But when I try to create yet another instance of HibernateTransactionManager with secondary data-source, I get a non-unique exception.

Do I require a secondary HibernateTransactionManager instance for the config I am posting or will 1 suffice? If required, how can I create one? Thank you.

Error log :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: primary_tx,extended_tx
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:271)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springfram
```

WebConfig.java :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ourapp.spring"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


 @Bean(name="primary_tx")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getPrimaryTransactionManager() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager txName= new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txName.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return txName;
    }

    @Bean(name="extended_tx")
    public HibernateTransactionManager txName() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager txName= new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txName.setSessionFactory(getExtendedSessionFactory().getObject());
        return txName;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory_origin")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(new DataSourceConfig().primaryDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.ourapp.spring");
        return sessionFactory;
    }

     @Bean
@Qualifier("sessionFactory_extended")
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getExtendedSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(new DataSourceConfig_Extended().secondaryDataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.ourapp.spring");
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Typical Service Layer method :

```
@Service
@Transactional("primary_tx")
public class ChatRoomMembersServiceImpl implements ChatRoomMembersService{


   private final ChatRoomMembersDAO chatRoomMembersDAO;

    @Autowired
    public ChatRoomMembersServiceImpl(ChatRoomMembersDAO chatRoomMembersDAO){
        this.chatRoomMembersDAO = chatRoomMembersDAO;
    }
}
```

Typical DAO layer method :

```
@Repository
@Transactional("primary_tx")
public class ChatRoomMembersDAOImpl implements ChatRoomMembersDAO{

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory_origin")
    private  SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory_extended")
    private  SessionFactory sessionFactory_extended;

}
```

Now, whenever required, I am referring to the extended SessionFactory instance. Right now, I have annotated DAO layer methods requiring extended sessionFactory with `secondary_tx`, but it's not working. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question

> Do I require to define separate TransactionManager for 2 data sources?

is **YES**

Java8 onwards you can have same annotation(provided that the annotation is marked @Repeatable) multiple times on a method. Other way to accomplish this is to gave a custom annotation which takes care of one of the datasources.

The exception you are getting is because there are two qualifying beans for transation management. You need a Qualifier for this.

Instead of:

```
@Bean(name="primary_tx")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getPrimaryTransactionManager() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager txName= new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txName.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return txName;
    }
```

Use

```
@Bean @Qualifier("primary_tx")

    public HibernateTransactionManager getPrimaryTransactionManager() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager txName= new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txName.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return txName;
    }
```

Now, Let say You want to make the transactions in my method m1 as atomic. The following is what you need

```
@Transactional("primary_tx")
public void m1(){
}
```

Comment: Where do I add this? I am simply using @Transactional annotation on methods where I require secondary Transaction. Thank you.

Comment: You got to put it on the method enclosing transactions. The way it works is pretty simple. It makes the transactions atomic i.e. either all will execute successfully or nothing will be committed

Comment: I changed it to name the HIbernateTransactionManager with Qualifier, but I get the same error. I also annotated all methods as you suggested. Note : I have 2 methods which return HibernateTransactionManager, each tied to a specific instance of SessionFactory. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @WeareBorg the message is pretty clear `expected single matching bean but found 2: primary_tx,extended_tx` :)  
Also, you need to remove it from class level all you don't want your all the methods to become transactional

Comment: I think there is some confusion. As you said, I would require 2 different TransactionManagers for 2 different data-sources, that's exactly how I have it now. Can you please update your answer to show how the 2 transactionManagers will be defined and called. Thank you. My non-transactional methods are out of service layer classes already. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173449/discussion-between-yates-and-we-are-borg).

Comment: Make sure you have added the `@EnableTransactionManagement` on the configuration file (WebConfig in your case)

Comment: I am in chat, EnableTransactionManagement is already there in Webconfig

Comment: Can you please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983141/spring-add-properties-file-externally    Thank you. :-)