# Spring : Add properties file externally

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, migration

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which we are preparing to setup application on different servers. As each server can have it's own database related configuration, we are hoping to use an external properties file(outside the war file) which can be read while project is starting. How do I go about this approach? 
For making it work, I have already moved application initialization code to Java, this way, static XML reading which we had before won't be required. 
But, we are unsure how to create and add a properties file dynamically which atleast has these 3 values(JDBC URL containing DB name, username, password). All tables, other data will be created automatically.

Here is the class where app is initialized :

WebConfig.java :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ourapp.spring"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    }


    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    }

    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("../resources/locale/messages.properties");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("../webapp/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DoNotTruncateMyUrls doNotTruncate(){
       return new DoNotTruncateMyUrls();
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("primary_tx")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getPrimaryTransactionManager() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager txName= new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txName.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return txName;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("extended_tx")
    public HibernateTransactionManager txName() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager txName= new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txName.setSessionFactory(getExtendedSessionFactory().getObject());
        return txName;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory_origin")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(new DataSourceConfig().primaryDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.ourapp.spring");
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory_extended")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getExtendedSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(new DataSourceConfig_Extended().secondaryDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.ourapp.spring");
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Thank you. :-)

Comment: are you using spring boot? If so you can use config server

Comment: @pvpkiran : No, Unfortunately I am using spring-mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you are looking for is Profiles( `@Profile or @Conditional` )

**Step1:**  Create a profile. The following is the example for prod profile. Similarly, you can create one for `dev` and `qa`

```
import javax.activation.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean;

@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/<SomePath>/app.properties")
public class ProductionProfileConfig {

    @Autowired Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(env.getProperty("dbName"));
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setResourceRef(true);
        jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(javax.sql.DataSource.class);
        return (DataSource) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
}
```

**Step2 Activate profiles**

> Spring honors two separate properties when determining which profiles
>   are active: `spring.profiles.active` and `spring.profiles.default`. If
>   spring.profiles.active is set, then its value determines which
>   profiles are active. But if spring .profiles.active isn’t set, then
>   Spring looks to spring.profiles.default. If neither
>   spring.profiles.active nor spring.profiles.default is set, then there
>   are no active profiles, and only those beans that aren’t defined as
>   being in a profile are created

**UPDATE**

Use `PropertyConfigurator.configure(Loader.getResource(<your-file-path>));` if the file is located outside the packaged war. Later you can simply inject values using `@Value or SPel`

Comment: Where will this file be located? On jetty especially this is a problem as Jetty unpacks the war in /tmp within some randomly named folder.

Comment: That's how you place it on classpath. If the file is inside the src folder directly use /file.properties

Comment: I am looking to place it outside the WAR file. Any way I can do it same way by placing it externally somewhere

Comment: Use PropertyConfigurator.configure(Loader.getResource(<your-file-path>));
Later you can simply inject values using @Value or SPel

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`

Create a bean like this

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer devPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
   PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   configurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("file:pathtToFile"));
   configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
   return configurer;
}
```

For example if you write file:/tmp/dev/*.properties . It will load all the properties file under /tmp/dev.

If you want to customize it based on differnt environment(dev, testing, production). then you can use `@Profile`  and create multiple beans.

```
@Bean
@Profile("dev")
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer devPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
   ..... // give dev properties file path
}


@Bean
@Profile("testing")
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer testPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
.....// give test properties file path
}

@Bean
@Profile("prod")
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer prodPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
.....// give prod properties file path
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a config manager, which will create configuration objects based on the name of properties file. For example,

`Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.getConfig("dbConfig");`

so, now your config object will contain all properties related to db. When you instantiate config object read all properties into this object.

Let's say your properties file contains following fields:

`user.name = "Tom"
user.password = "pass"`

Next time when you need "user.name", you would just do `config.getString("user.name")`

Comment: Where will this db.config located?

Comment: better approach would be to create a separate web service which would serve your properties only

Comment: Even if a new service is created, I would have to load the database values during startup. How would a separate webservice change it